# Pandas: Apply function that references other rows & other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a function to use in a `df`.apply() that references 1) other rows, and 2) another DatetimeIndex.

```
dt_index = DatetimeIndex(['2022-09-16', '2022-12-16', '2023-03-10', '2023-06-16',
               '2023-09-15', '2023-12-15', '2024-03-15', '2024-06-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

In regards to the main df:

```
df.index =   DatetimeIndex(['2022-08-30', '2022-08-31', '2022-09-01', '2022-09-02',
               '2022-09-03', '2022-09-04', '2022-09-05', '2022-09-06',
               '2022-09-07', '2022-09-08',
               ...
               '2024-08-20', '2024-08-21', '2024-08-22', '2024-08-23',
               '2024-08-24', '2024-08-25', '2024-08-26', '2024-08-27',
               '2024-08-28', '2024-08-29'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='index', length=731, freq=None)

df =                 3M      1Y      2Y         
                                                                         
2022-08-30    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.000000  
2022-08-31    2.50    2.50    2.50    2.500000  
2022-09-01    3.50    3.50    3.50    3.500000  
2022-09-02    5.50    5.50    5.50    5.833333  
2022-09-03    5.65    5.65    5.65    5.983333  
           ...     ...     ...         ...  ...    
2024-08-25  630.75  615.75  599.75  607.750000 
2024-08-26  631.75  616.75  600.75  608.750000  
2024-08-27  632.75  617.75  601.75  609.750000  
2024-08-28  633.75  618.75  602.75  610.750000  
2024-08-29  634.75  619.75  603.75  611.750000
```

My goal is to use a function that:

1. For each index value, `x`, in `df`, find the closest two values in `dt_index` (have this below)
2. Then, in `df`, return:  `(x - id_low) / (id_high - id_low)`

   ```
    def transform(x, dt_index):
        id_low = dt_index.iloc[dt_index.get_loc(x, method ='ffill')]
        id_high = dt_index.iloc[dt_index.get_loc(x, method ='bfill')]
   ```

It's part 2 that I dont know how to write, as it references other rows in `df` outside of the one the function is being applied to.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: in your `.apply()` you're using `axis=1`, right?

Comment: it's a row-wise operation (can't remember if thats =1?)

Comment: Yup, it would be axis = 1 (apply the function to each row)

Comment: by `x - id_low` you mean to subtract the rows that have the indices `x` and `id_low`, right ?

Comment: Correct.    (Row[x] - Row[id_low]) / (Row[id_high] - Row[id_low])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing inaccuracies in your code,

You can simply reference your dataframe `df` inside the function:

```py
def transform(x, dt_index):
    id_low = dt_index[dt_index.get_indexer([x.name], method ='ffill')][0]
    id_high = dt_index[dt_index.get_indexer([x.name], method ='bfill')][0]

    return (x - df.loc[id_low]) / (df.loc[id_high] - df.loc[id_low])

df.transform(transform, dt_index=dt_index, axis=1)
```

**Example:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(6, 4))
dt_index = pd.Index([0,2,5])

# Result:

          0         1         2         3
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  0.500000  0.500000  0.500000  0.500000
2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
4  0.666667  0.666667  0.666667  0.666667
5       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

> Note:
>
> `NaN` values are due to the mathematically undefined result for `0/0`:
>
> when `id_low == id_high == x.name`.

Comment: so thats what I'm actually trying myself now, but I'm getting an InvalidIndexError.  I think I have something off in the id_low, id_high bit

Comment: unfort no.  I think the issue is in my id_low / id_high thing

Comment: do you know of a future_proof way of doing get_loc?  Doesn't seem to like timestamps...

Comment: `.get_indexer` example of usage: `pd.Index([0,2,5]).get_indexer([4], method ='ffill')`

Comment: `'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'iloc'` -- use just the square brackets

Comment: @keynesiancross after a lot of debugging, I have the result